# Programming a Discord bot in Python- How do I make the bot react to its own message?

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to make the bot react to its own message right after sending it. Here's my code:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if any(word in msg for word in submission_triggers):
    channel = client.get_channel(805132829691215882)
    mention = message.author.name
    image_url = message.attachments[0].url
    em = discord.Embed(title = f"Created by: {mention}", color = random.choice(colors))
    em.set_image(url = image_url)
    await channel.send(embed = em)
    await client.add_reaction("<:ThumbsUp:796201003816321034>")
```

When this is triggers, it sends the embed but does not react to it. I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'add_reaction'
```

Not quite sure how to  fix this. I'm new to programming, so any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting the error obviously because of an attribute problem. That means `Bot` cannot add reactions to a message. Also, how did you expect to add a reaction without specifying the message to be added? `discord.Message` object has attribute `add_reaction`. You have to get the instance of it. You can simply assign a variable to the sent message then add reaction.

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if any(word in msg for word in submission_triggers):
    channel = client.get_channel(805132829691215882)
    mention = message.author.name
    image_url = message.attachments[0].url
    em = discord.Embed(title = f"Created by: {mention}", color = random.choice(colors))
    em.set_image(url = image_url)
    sent = await channel.send(embed = em)
    await sent.add_reaction("<:ThumbsUp:796201003816321034>")
```